# Picking up html and include into php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xampp

I am an amateur in PHP. I am writing a file named 'index.php' and its content I have put in a file known as 'Built.html'

**Index.php**

```
<body> 
 <?php include 'built.html';?>
</body>
```

**Built.html**

```
<div id=mainContent> 
  <p>I love 'Hermione Granger.'</p>
</div>
```

I am using xampp, and on going to "Localhost/myfolder/index.php" (My files are in this folder), I am unable to get the content picked from html file to the index.php file. Am I doing anything wrong?

**ANSWER:**

I got it done. I think there was some issue in 'Xampp' host. I restarted it, and got the file done. Thnx, *"vihan"* for providing some more options for getting external file included in my php. Though, it was not so relevant to my question, I appreciated it!

Comment: Are those two files in the same directory? and one file you posted starts with `B` but the name in include starts with `b`?

Comment: Are you sure the index.php file runs on your server.

Comment: why not using some js for this?

Comment: I think you should try this : `<?php include('built.html') ; ?>`

Comment: @Abhishek - wrong. Your answer must have been a downvote, if you gave.

Comment: @Peterson : why so  ?? I have used this and I don't see what is wrong in that Sir]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your getting, an iframe might be more strait forward . Don't use this if you are just trying to get text or something else:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <iframe src="built.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

---

#### php

PHP, you may need to make sure the path is actually correct:

```
include __DIR__ + '/built.html';
```

Also, I've known this works for some:

```
include('built.html');
```

---

Or JavaScript:

```
var xhr = (new window.XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        document.getElementById('mainContent').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'built.html', false);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Please note that an `iframe` works totally different than simply including HTML. In most cases this is definitely not a solution I'd recommend.

Comment: I think there is already a provision in PHP for this... It should work fine with `include('built.html')`.. For something as simple as include I dont think using JavaScript would be viable

Comment: No, I want to do it with PHP. I want to know why my divs are not loaded. ;(